# Quadratic Form Single Summation notation

Tags: mathematical-economics, optimization, linear-algebra

I'm trying to translate what feels like a double summation notation , compacted into a single summation. It's the summation definition of quadratic forms.

$Q(x_1, x_2.....x_n)=\sum_{i \le j}a_{ij}x_ix_j$

I assume quadratic forms can be written as the less compact double summation?

$Q(x_1, x_2.....x_n)=\sum_{i =1}^n \sum_{j =1}^n a_{ij}x_ix_j$

To count this we would:

1. Fix the outer summation first, so in this case we would be fixing rows and going across columns. Alternately we could switch the summation so we fixed columns and counted rows. This holds for any $n•m$ matrix i believe?
2. **Question:** I suppose the $i \le j$ notation has to correspond to this. But it's not immediately clicking?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686123/notation-what-does-sum-ij-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum $\sum_{i \le j}=a_{ij}x_ix_j$ goes over all indices $(i,j)$ with $i\leq j$. We can do that by either summing over all $i$ and then for each $i$ all $j\geq i$, which would give us
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i}^n=a_{ij}x_ix_j,$$
or we could sum over all $j$ and then look at $i\leq j$, which would give us
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^j=a_{ij}x_ix_j.$$

However, for [general quadratic forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form), one does not restrict to $i\leq j$, which would correspond to the additional restriction that $a_{ij}=0$ for $i>j$, which need not hold in general.

Comment: Hi michael, is the line at the beginning with two $i$'s a typo? "We can do that by either summing over all $i$ and then for each $i$ all $j\geq i$," should it be: ...then for each $j$ all $j\geq i$

Comment: No now i read it again i don't think it is a typo. I think i was just miss understanding. But please confirm it is indeed correct.

Comment: I don’t see any typo.

Comment: Yeah it was sounding weird to me, but I understand why it’s right now! Thanks for checking!